# How to pass selected option value to parameter of new function

Tags: javascript

Thank you in advance for any help I am a relative newcomer to javascript so please bear with me if some of my terminology is wrong. I have the below code and functions and need to pass the result of function run to the arameter of function AddToCart . I can get both functions to work independently and id="resultPrintValue" always returns the correct number value. Basically how do I get that value into the AddToCart parameter? I have seen similar questions and have tried several suggestions such as putting function inside the parameter but all return Not a Number (NaN) - I seem to be missing something.

```
<!-- select option - calls function run onchange -->

<select name="Print" id="Print"  onchange="run()" > 
<option value="0">select print size </option>        
<option  value="1">Lush Tapestry Print on Paper 50cm x 25cm £125</option> 
<option  value="2">Another print £25</option>
<option  value="3">he original £4000000</option>
<select>

<!-- code below returns the value (0-3) correctly of selected option. Need to pass this result in function AddToCart -->

<p>Your id is: </p><p id="resultPrintValue"> </p>  


<!-- Stuck with code  to put value in parameter of function AddToCart - If I hard code a number 0-3 then AddToCart works fine -->


functions are as below

function run() {
document.getElementById("resultPrintValue").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Print").value;
return (resultPrintValue)
}

function AddToCart(x)
{
var product_index = cart_products.indexOf(x);
if (product_index > -1) 
{
cart_quantities[x]++;
}
else
{
cart_products.push(x);
cart_quantities[x] = 1;
}
ShowPopup("The print was added to your basket!");
UpdateCart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to be passed in as a parameter. Simply set a variable to be equal to the return value of the run function.

```
function AddToCart()
{
var x = this.run()
...
}
```

Comment: Apologies should have added I am using  <a href="javascript:AddToCart();"><button>Add to basket</button> </a> to call second function

Comment: does that hit the function properly if you don't use the parameter? Because if so, just call another function like <a href="javascript:PreAddToCart();">. In that new function call this.AddToCart(value) with the parameter.

Not sure if I'm understanding the problem properly

Comment: OK I call <a href="javascript:AddToCart();"><button>Add to basket</button>  (button on screen to select option and call AddToCart function - if I put a hard coded number in the function call eg AddToCart(2) it works but I need the 2 to be replaced with the id="resultPrintValue" which is always a number - have a look at sallygatie.co.uk/shop

Answer (score 0):

```
        var cart_quantities = [];
        var cart_products = [];
        function run() {
            var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("Print").value, 10);
            document.getElementById("resultPrintValue").innerHTML = value;
            AddToCart(value);
        }
        function AddToCart(x) {
            var product_index = cart_products.indexOf(x);
            if (product_index === -1) {
                cart_products.push(x);
            }

            ShowPopup("The print was added to your basket!");
            UpdateCart();
        }
```